# Loading a list of dict into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a list of dictionary like this, wanted to load this into a data frame for a couple of Keys in the object.

The data frame I would like looks like

ID -- retweet_count -- favorite_count

```
tweet_list = ['{"created_at": "Tue Aug 01 00:17:27 +0000 2017", "id": 892177421306343426, "id_str": "892177421306343426", "full_text": "This is Tilly. She\'s just checking pup on you.", "truncated": false, "display_text_range": [0, 138], "contributors": null, "is_quote_status": false, "retweet_count": 6514, "favorite_count": 33819, "favorited": false, "retweeted": false, "possibly_sensitive": false, "possibly_sensitive_appealable": false, "lang": "en"}',
 '{"created_at": "Sun Jul 30 15:58:51 +0000 2017", "id": 891689557279858688, "id_str": "891689557279858688", "full_text": "This is Darla. She commenced a snooze mid meal.", "truncated": false, "display_text_range": [0, 79], "entities": {"hashtags": [], "symbols": [],  "following": true, "follow_request_sent": false, "notifications": false, "translator_type": "none"}, "geo": null, "coordinates": null, "place": null, "contributors": null, "is_quote_status": false, "retweet_count": 8964, "favorite_count": 42908, "favorited": false, "retweeted": false, "possibly_sensitive": false, "possibly_sensitive_appealable": false, "lang": "en"}']
```

Comment: is this list of strings or list of dicts or what kind of list is this `tweet_list`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and then **ask a question**. The post should give appropriate context for the task - by showing *exactly what should happen* when the code runs, and what *does happen* when existing code (if any) runs. It should explain what the **problem** is, not just the task that needs to be performed. After making these things clear, ask what you want to know about - starting with a question word like "why" or "how", and ending with a question mark (`?`).

Comment: Those are not a valid dicts. Dicts are not surrounded by quotation marks. Also it contains `false` which should either be `'false'` (in quotes, as `string`) or `False` (capitalized, al `bool`). Similar problem with `null`, which would be `None`in python or a `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a reporoducible data first:

```
new_list = [
{"created_at": "Tue Aug 01 00:17:27 +0000 2017",
 "id": 892177421306343426,
 "id_str": "892177421306343426", 
 "full_text": "This is Tilly. She\'s just checking pup on you.",
 "truncated": False, 
 "display_text_range": [0, 138],
 "contributors": None,
 "is_quote_status": False,
 "retweet_count": 6514,
 "favorite_count": 33819,
 "favorited": False,
 "retweeted": False,
 "possibly_sensitive": False,
 "possibly_sensitive_appealable": False,
 "lang": "en"},

{"created_at": "Sun Jul 30 15:58:51 +0000 2017",
 "id": 891689557279858688, 
 "id_str": "891689557279858688", 
 "full_text": "This is Darla. She commenced a snooze mid meal.", 
 "truncated": False,
 "display_text_range": [0, 79],
 "entities": {"hashtags": [], "symbols": [],  "following": True, 
 "follow_request_sent": False, "notifications": False, 
  "translator_type": "none"},
 "geo": None, "coordinates": None,
 "place": None,
 "contributors": None,
 "is_quote_status": False,
 "retweet_count": 8964,
 "favorite_count": 42908,
"favorited": False,
"retweeted": False,
"possibly_sensitive": False,
"possibly_sensitive_appealable": False,
"lang": "en"}]
```

To clean it you can use :

```
import json
new_list=[]
for i in range(len(tweet_list)):
  new_list.append(json.loads(tweet_list[i]))
```

Then you can use :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd. DataFrame. from_dict(new_list)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=df[['id','retweet_count','favorite_count']])
```

[image: df]

[image: df2]

Answer (score 0):

You have actually list of `str`s, which were created by *serializing* `dict`s using [JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159/) (not `false` rather than `False` and `null` rather than `None`). Apply `json.loads` at them and then create DataFrame, consider following simple example

```
import json
import pandas as pd
data = ['{"A":1,"B":null}','{"A":null,"B":2}','{"A":null,"B":null}']
df = pd.DataFrame(map(json.loads,data))
print(df)
```

gives output

```
     A    B
0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  2.0
2  NaN  NaN
```

Explanation: I use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) built-in function to apply `json.loads` to each element of `list` and then create `pandas.DataFrame` from them.